# Getting exception during insert in spring integrated JPA model

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-orm

I am using Spring integrated with hibernate and using JPA annotations in entity object. I created this project to test CRUD operations using this combination. I am able to load data from db but facing issue with insertion.

I have 2 tables.

> Employee: ID, NAME, AGE, DEPT
>
> Dept: DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME

Employee.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
    public class Employee implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name="ID")
        private int id;

        @Column(name="NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="AGE")
        private int age;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="DEPT", referencedColumnName="DEPT_NAME", updatable=false, insertable=false)
        private Dept department;

//Other getters and setters
```

Dept.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEPT")
public class Dept implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="DEPT_ID")
    private int deptId;

    @Column(name="DEPT_NAME")
    private String deptName;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="department")
    private List<Employee> employee;
```

DAO class:

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

    private HibernateTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory factory){
        template = new HibernateTemplate(factory);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        template.saveOrUpdate(employee);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
        return template.find("from Employee");
    }
}
```

My Spring MVC controller class

```
    @Controller
    public class EmployeeController {

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeDAO empDao;

        @Autowired
        private DeptDAO deptDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/loadInsertForm", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String loadInsertForm(Model model){
            List<Dept> depList = deptDao.getDept();
            model.addAttribute("deptObjList", depList);
            return "empInsertForm";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/insertEmpValues", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String insertEmployee(Employee employee){
            empDao.saveEmployee(employee);
            return "loadEmpList";
        }

@RequestMapping(value="/loadEmpList", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String displayEmpDetails(Model model){
        List<Employee> emp = empDao.getEmployee();
        model.addAttribute("empList", emp);
        return "empList";
    }
    }
```

My jsp class to get inputs from user.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="insertEmpValues.spr" commandName="employee">
        <table width="30%">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Employee ID : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="id" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Employee Name : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Age : </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Department : </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="department">
                        <c:forEach items="${deptObjList}" var="dept">
                            <option id="${dept.deptName}">${dept.deptName}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

I know that the content is bit more here. But I thought of giving all possible inputs. So given all required files.

Now I am able to load values from table, but during insert, I get some problem that I am listing out here.

**Problem 1:**
If I input ID, Name, age and dept in the input form & click on submit, I get following exception.

```
exception 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'employee' on field 'department': rejected value [POS]; codes [typeMismatch.employee.department,typeMismatch.department,typeMismatch.com.spring.persistence.Dept,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [employee.department,department]; arguments []; default message [department]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.spring.persistence.Dept' for property 'department'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.spring.persistence.Dept] for property 'department': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**Problem 2:**
The other question is, I am using Employee ID as auto generated in entity class, but if I didn't input ID in the form and click submit, I am getting following exception.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'employee' on field 'department': rejected value [VZW]; codes [typeMismatch.employee.department,typeMismatch.department,typeMismatch.com.spring.persistence.Dept,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [employee.department,department]; arguments []; default message [department]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.spring.persistence.Dept' for property 'department'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.spring.persistence.Dept] for property 'department': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
Field error in object 'employee' on field 'id': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.employee.id,typeMismatch.id,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [employee.id,id]; arguments []; default message [id]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'id'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I even googled for the answer, but couldn't get proper answer. Can someone help me on this?
Thanks,

P.S: I didn't keep spring configuration and web.xml files here. As I mentioned already, the retrieve operation is working, so I believe that the configuration should be good.

Comment: hey man i have the same problem did u find the problem. webinit is the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure problem is not in JPA, it is related the way that spring use to convert form parameters in a valid Object within the controller. 
Basically two problems are about the same issue:

Values coming from the form are always String's, so bean that are exposed in the controller should have all their attributes as String to be able pass parameters of the form into bean properties. This process I think is named binding.

This error is why I said:
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.spring.persistence.Dept' for property 'department', always String is send. but not all your properties are String, one of them is a Dept so conversion can not be done.

To solve this issue, you could use a POJO that contains only Strings, the easiest solution, all the parameters in the form should be named as properties in the bean. Why you dont try to use something like a bean forms instead of the entity beans within the controller?

Or a more complete solution I think is implement something with @ModelAttribute and @InitBinder, not very sure about it, so beware with this comment XD.

Comment: I thought of using separate VO class here instead of this entity class. But during retrieval, I've seen the entity is populated with values of corresponding type correctly. The problem arrives only with insertion. Let me try including one more field of String type for deptName and see what happens.

Comment: In your code you have      ** @JoinColumn(name="DEPT", referencedColumnName="DEPT_NAME", updatable=false, insertable=false)  ** try removing insertable=false. Also remember the key of Dept is an DEPT_ID not a String, using the joincolumn annotation only override the name of the column.

Comment: And try enabled CascadeType.PERSIST

Answer (score -1):

**Problem 1 :** In strongly advised you to use  tag from Spring JSTL. it will resolve this error and probably future errors.

**Problem 2 :** Don't use primitive in your POJO. And also I think it is related to Problem 1

Comment: Ok Thanks, let me try them. Give me some time.